# Empty file named "en" in root directory

Tags: finder, file

I recently discovered a file named "en" in the root directory of my Macintosh HD. It's completely empty and was last edited today, around the time I logged in on my Mac.

`-rw-r--r--     1 root  wheel     0B  2 mrt 13:03 en`

What's it for, and can I safely remove this file?

I'm on macOS Sierra (10.12.4 – 16E195).
`stat-x /en` produces the following output:

```
  File: "/en"
  Size: 0            FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)         Uid: (    0/    root)  Gid: (    0/   wheel)
Device: 1,6   Inode: 21181583    Links: 1
Access: Sun Apr  2 21:39:13 2017
Modify: Thu Mar  2 13:03:59 2017
Change: Thu Mar  2 13:03:59 2017
```

As recommended in the comments I've searched for files modified around the modification date of the `en` file:

`find / -newerct "March 2 13:03" ! -newerct "March 2 13:04" -print` produces a lot of "Permission Denied" errors for system folders, but what I have noticed is that `com.10baseT.IPScannerMac` frequently appears in the search results:

```
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.apple.metal
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.apple.metal/Intel Iris Pro Graphics
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.apple.metal/Intel Iris Pro Graphics/functions.data
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.apple.metal/Intel Iris Pro Graphics/functions.maps
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.apple.metal/libraries.data
/private/var/folders/p6/ssbyq7rs4pnbcr2bg4kxpq740000gn/C/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/com.apple.metal/libraries.maps
/Users/Max/Library/Application Scripts/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac
/Users/Max/Library/Caches/storedownloadd/fsCachedData/A63D401C-5EB5-468E-B565-86600D47481C
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Container.plist
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Caches
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Caches/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Caches/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Cache.db-wal
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Caches/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/fsCachedData
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Caches/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/fsCachedData/4D6282BC-C902-4837-BD9A-73456131131D
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Caches/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/fsCachedData/83F0EAAA-C78F-450B-84F1-E6FA79535BED
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Preferences
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac/Data/Library/Preferences/com.10baseT.IPScannerMac.plist
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/WebKitCache/Version 9/Blobs/1A36280BA44942F3BD0922062DC52EEF81DE915A
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/WebKitCache/Version 9/Blobs/1B51C08D4B4F8D0B63AB5AA4B5178001DC9BD0AB
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/WebKitCache/Version 9/Records/No partition/Resource/11E09CF941CE1E92FFDA953BD73522861402B0EA
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/WebKitCache/Version 9/Records/No partition/Resource/11E09CF941CE1E92FFDA953BD73522861402B0EA-blob
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/WebKitCache/Version 9/Records/No partition/Resource/8A45B783D137478611F2F285B4CB0B1E1EA5FACB
/Users/Max/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore/WebKitCache/Version 9/Records/No partition/Resource/8A45B783D137478611F2F285B4CB0B1E1EA5FACB-blob
```

Comment: Can you link the file (and its modification date) to some app/binary (or a launch daemon/agent) installed/updated or launched for the first time on March 2, 2017 13:03?

Comment: @klanomath Unfortunately not, I have no idea what app or binary is causing this file to be created and modified. I do have a few apps that run on startup, including ControlPlane which in its turn runs some other apps like OneDrive and Dropbox.

Comment: No, I haven't actually. I think that it's around the time that I booted up my Mac however, so I expect a lot of results. I'll look up how to do so.

Comment: Oh, oops! You're completely right @klanomath. April 2. I'm currently looking up how to use the `find` command.

Comment: I've added the search results to my question. Thanks for the heads up on the date which I had entered wrongly!

Comment: I just installed 10base-t's IP Scanner for Mac. But it doesn't create any files in the root folder. Maybe some other feature... - did you purchase the app or is it the free version?

Comment: It's the free version, I too suspect that it is likely to be more of a coincidence.

Comment: I don't think it's a pure coincidence. The file name *en* suggests a relation to an Ethernet interface (en0, en1...). First I suspected some kind of license file (which other apps also use, but not in the root folder and usually with random alpha-numericals and preceded by a dot > invisible). But it isn't. I think you can safely delete the file - with the question and all necessary data to restore it available here (`sudo touch -t 201703021303.59 /en`)

Comment: I've removed the file - My Mac's still running :). Thanks for the suggestions, your explanation does make sense indeed. I think you could post your suggestion as an answer, because I don't think there are many other explanations left and I mostly wanted to know if I could safely delete it.